# Is it possible to provide sonar-project.properties to sonarlint-cli?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

My objective is to run sonar scan and provide early feed back on defects without uploading scan result to sonar server.

I am planning to use sonarlint-cli to scan code as soon as Git merge request is crated. This will help me to report issues early without running full sonar scan.

I already have multiple module sonar-project.properties at the root folder of source code.

Can I use same sonar-project.properties with sonarlint-cli?

Comment: Why not use the [GitHub Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin) ? "*The GitHub Plugin serves only one purpose: analyse GitHub pull requests without pushing results to SonarQube. Any issues that are found are published as comments on the pull request.*"

Comment: Seems like a nice option, I will have to check with tools team, if this plugin in installed with sonar server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible to feed sonarlint-cli with sonar-project.properties. You must use a dedicated sonarlint.json configuration file. See http://www.sonarlint.org/commandline/index.html

Comment: I think for my use case  GitHub Plugin will work. Thanks

Comment: Broken link; Sonarlint-cli is no longer supported - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47079748/4989143