# Sonarlint command line version dropped?

Tags: sonarlint

It would appear that Sonarsource has discontinued development on the command line instance of the sonarlint tool.  The link to the page on the sonarlint website now returns a 404 and there is no mention of the product on the sonarlint website.

Does this mean that there will no longer be a command line version of sonarlint?

The reason that I am asking this is that I would like to implement a build process that runs static analysis of the code for developers and also as part of the CI process on our Jenkins server.  Whilst this can be achieved using various other plugins (checkstyle, etc.) the decision to start using Squid rules and deprecating older checkstyle, findbugs, etc. rules in Sonar makes alignment of the build process with the outcome reported by Sonar difficult; there are some rules in squid that are not readily matchable.  For this reason I was looking for a way for developers to run a local Sonar analysis which is the same as that which is run by Jenkins during CI.  (This is basic build and development best practice to align the local developer build with that executed by the CI server).

Either the sonar preview mode or the sonarlint command line tool would have allowed our build to do this, but it appears that Sonarsource does not understand the value of the practice and has decided to no longer support (by on going development) either method, which, in my opinion is a mistake.  I hope that by raising this question they may consider again whether and how to support Sonar analysis for developers that does not require and IDE or editor plugin.  My preference for this would to remove the deprecation of the preview mode analysis in the sonar runner so that we can confidently create processes that rely on it.

Answer (score 7):

The SonarLint CLI version is not developed nor supported anymore.
It will be dropped completely soon, please find more info here (post by a SonarSource representative):

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/WlALjVzp-OE/Ev3QpnaOBAAJ

You might go with Sonar Scanner:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner

Comment: I would be happy to go with Sonar Scanner, but the functionality in it is reported as deprecated (as mentioned in my original post) and this is a concern because it means that SonarSource have license to pull the rug on the functionality at any time.

Comment: the second link (concerning Sonar Scanner) is also dead (404)